# how to simple add an object to a collection in hibernate from client

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to add an object to a collection in my client view and to save it on server with hibernate/jpa mechanism.

Here is the problem:
Take a Group object which can contains Account objects.

On my client view (gwt), I create a new group (so the id is null) and I add to this group some accounts (where ids exist). BUT these accounts are initialized in client with their id and pseudo only via a suggest box (because I don't want to load password and other stuff in my client view)

When my group returns to server, I try to save it with my dao and I've got this error:
not-null property references a null or transient value

Here is my association in Group object:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public Set<Account> getAccounts()
{
    return accounts;
}
```

so the persist must be done automatically. But I think the problem is that I use partial account objects with existing id.

My question is: How can I add a simple association (just add a record in the manyToMany table) without loading all objects that I want to add (because I don't need it, I just want to add an association between two id)

EDIT:
more information by example:
I've got a group which properties are 
id:"G1"
name:"group1"

I've got the account which properties are
id:"A1"
pseudo:"jerome"
password:"pass1"
status:"enabled"
birthday:"xxxx"
...

From my client interface (done with gwt) I load the group1 object
From an autcompletion I load Account objects but only with field id and pseudo (I don't want to load all the object).
I add the Account object "Jerome" with id "A1" to my group.

I send my group to server to save it.
In server I use a transactional method which save the group by calling:
groupDAO.update(myGroup1)

As my Account object in this Group object is partially loaded, it causes an error.

So, How can I add the association between my group and account without loading the entire object Account ? I don't want this sort of code:

```
List newList = new ArrayList();
for (Account acc : myGroup1.getAccounts())
{
    Account accLoaded = accountDAO.findById(acc.getId());
    newList.add(accLoaded);
}

myGroup1.setAccounts(newList);
groupDAO.save(myGroup1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal:

> I just want to add an association between two id **without loading the entire object Account**

You said:

> I think the problem is that **i use partial account objects** with existing id

You are right. Suppose the following

```
public class Account {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer accountNumber;

    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(nullable=false)
    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return this.accountNumber;
    }

}
```

So when you call

```
Group group = new Group();

// Notice as shown bellow accountNumber is null
Account account = new Account();
account.setId(1);

group.addAccount(account);

entityManager.persist(group);
```

So because of CascadeType.PERSIST, you are saying

> Save each referenced Account

But each referenced Account accountNumber property is null. It explains why you get your exception

**Instead of loading a fully initialized Account** You can use something like

```
// If you do not want to hit the database
// Because you do not need a fully initialized Account
// Just use getReference method
Account account = entityManager.getReference(Account.class, new Integer(accountId));
```

So it does not make sense you load each fully initialized Account without any purpose or reason.

regards,

Comment: Woa ! Exactly what I want !

Thank you so much !